# How to create multiple fields of the table column, submitted for a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I don't exactly know what is the correct title for this question, sorry.

I have a `Question` model, a user should enter lets say 5 question and then submit them at the time to questions table.

The problem is it is only submitting one question, that is the last question.

**How can I make it submit all question fields at the same time?**

views:

```
<% question_numbering = 0 %>

<%= simple_form_for(@quiz, html: {class: 'form-vertical' }) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages_question' %>

    <div>
        <%=  %>
        question <%= question_numbering += 1 %><br>
        <%= f.input_field :content, :rows => 3, :style => "width:80%", :placeholder => "enter your question."  %><br>
        question <%= question_numbering += 1 %><br>
        <%= f.input_field :content, :rows => 3, :style => "width:80%", :placeholder => "enter your question."  %><br>
        question <%= question_numbering += 1 %><br>
        <%= f.input_field :content, :rows => 3, :style => "width:80%", :placeholder => "enter your question."  %><br>
        question <%= question_numbering += 1 %><br>
        <%= f.input_field :content, :rows => 3, :style => "width:80%", :placeholder => "enter your question."  %><br>
        question <%= question_numbering += 1 %><br>
        <%= f.input_field :content, :rows => 3, :style => "width:80%", :placeholder => "enter your question."  %><br>
    </div>
    <%= f.submit 'Submit', :class => "btn btn-default" %>
<% end %>
```

**Controller:**

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @quiz = Question.new
    @questioner = Questioner.new
  end

  def new
    @quiz = Question.new(quiz_params)
  end

  def show
    @quiz = Question.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @quiz = find(params[:id])
    raise "Question Not edited!" unless @quiz
  end

  def create
    @quiz = Question.new(quiz_params)

    if @quiz.save
      flash[:warning] = 'You have successfully posted the questions!'
      redirect_to questions_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "Please review the problems below."
      # render 'new'
      redirect_to questions_path
    end
  end

  private

    def quiz_params
      params.require(:question).permit(:content, :answered, :questioner_id, :category_id)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently working with the Question resource - it only really makes sense to create one question at a time since they don't exist as a collection but as individual units.

If you had another resource, like Quiz, which had many Questions - then it would make sense to create multiple questions at once.

You will need to create Quiz as a seperate resource with a `has_many` association with Questions.

Check out [this great Railscast on nested forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) which should help you with this (this is where I started learning Rails).

Comment: @thanks man, that seems helpful. I have been searching for a resource. Seems that the cast was made for rails 2, can I find better updated tutorial?

Comment: yes I have a questioner resource. a questioner has many questions. and a question belongs to the questioner(questioner attributes are name and email)
..also there is category resource also a question belongs to a category, and a category has many questions.

I want to be  able to submit the many questions asked by one user(questioner) at a time. thanks

Comment: The Railscast isn't new but it's still good and this is still how you would do this in the latest version of Rails (the updated version is just about how to make this snazzier with javascript).

Comment: You need a separate controller for a Quiz/Questioner and then have a nested form for Questions within that Quiz/Questioner. The Railscast should show you how to do this.

Comment: I am following it now